# Is there an Android InputStream class that times out?

Tags: android, timeout, inputstream

I am currently using an `InputStream` in my application (`import java.io.InputStream`) and have run into an issue regarding timing out. The way the `InputStream` seems to work is that it waits for a certain amount of bits and then proceeds. For my application this works a lot of the time, but there are cases where I am expecting the read to fail due to timeout. Does anyone know a way to do this?

I have found many examples of creating threads to run alongside the `read()` function and cancel it, but I was wondering if there is an existing class which lets me use an `InputStream` that times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This largely depends on where you are reading from. If it is from a file (or local) socket, there is no timeout. If it is from a remote socket, you can specify timeout when creating the socket. If it times out you should get an exception. Using threads/`AsyncTask` is the way to go, but you generally cannot interrupt a blocked read, unless you are using Java NIO.

And no, it is not ridiculous, how do you propose for it to 'time out on its own'? Someone has to signal the timeout, and that someone is either some sort of monitor thread or the OS raising an error.

Comment: By time out on its own, I meant a method which takes a parameter as a timeout length. Didn't seem to crazy to me. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `AsyncTask<>` for this.  You can try to start reading the stream asynchronously and then at a time of your choosing cancel the task, rather than blocking your UI.  Documentation **[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)**

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading into it now, but this still seems like too much of a hassle. It seems ridiculous that there isn't an input stream that times out on its own.